# Display data from input fields in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon everyone.

I have a dropdown with two input fields inside. Name and Price.

I would like to display the name and price after I click `Set` button that it appears in the same dropdown but on top of input fields.

Here is how it looks in my app currently, I enter name and price by myself.

[image]

As you can see in a first field there is a name and in the second there is a number and I wan't to store it under `Price Alert History` after clicking `Set` button.

Here is how I wish it will look. It's just an example which was made in photoshop. The main thing that I want to see name and price on top of input field.

[image]

**CODE HERE**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button} from "react-bootstrap";

const symbols = [
  "ADABTC",
  "AIONBTC",
  "ALGOBTC",
  "ARDRBTC",
  "KAVABTC",
  "ETHBTC",
  "ETCBTC"
];

function PriceTriggerField() {
    
 const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
 const [searchSymbol, setSearchSymbol] = React.useState([]);
 const handleChangeTerm = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };
const handleChangeSymbol = event => {
    setSearchSymbol(event.target.value);
  };
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const results = symbols.filter(symbols =>
      symbols.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
    setSearchSymbol(results);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>

        <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChangeTerm}
      /> 

       <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Price"
      />

    {
        searchTerm.length > 0 && searchSymbol.map(item => <li onClick={(() => setSearchTerm(item) )}>{item}</li>)
    }
      <Button variant="secondary">Set</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default PriceTriggerField;
```

Comment: You probably can save those values into a variable and just when you hit the "Set" button you can update the state

Comment: @NikBerko thanks for answer! Any example that I can refer to, if possible?

Comment: of course, I added a simple example, I hope this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

this is just a simple example with only one variable, but of course, you can do that for as many variables as you wish.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  let tmpName;

  const onChange = e => {
    tmpName = e.target.value;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={onChange} />
      <button onClick={() => setName(tmpName)}>set</button>
      name: {name}
    </div>
  );
}
```